# Wiener2Filter in Matlab equivalence in Java

Tags: java, android-studio, opencv, image-processing

Hello I am working on an image processing algorithm which is implemented as an android app using java. Any idea or implementation of the wiener2filter of matlab in java because i found it is very effective for noise elimination..
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will need to show what you've done so far at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convole in both axis directions.
see getGaussianBlurFilter in http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Advanced-Graphics/GaussianBlurDemo.htm for java example.